# Use of Classname(const Classname&); constructor oveloading in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, copy-constructor, constructor-overloading

I don't know what it is called so I'll show the code...maybe it is related to constructor overloading :

```
class Classname{
public:
      Classname(Class1& pClass1,Class2& pClass2);
private:
      Classname(const Classname&);
      void operator=(const Classname&);
};
```

What do the 2 statements in private section do ?

Comment: That's 'copy constructor' and 'copy assignment operator'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the '*copy constructor*' and '*copy assignement operator*' in private is just a way to forbid their use as they will raise an error when used outside of this class.

If you really want to forbid their use, I would suggest doing it this way :

```
class Classname
{
public:
      Classname(Class1& pClass1,Class2& pClass2);
      Classname(const Classname&) = delete;
      void operator=(const Classname&) = delete;
private:
      ...
};
```